# How to create validation Message for fields in razor MVC using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, requiredfieldvalidator, validationmessage

I want to create field validation in my razor view. 
This is quite easy because the MVC will automatically generate the **validationMessageFor** for us.

As what I have read that, we are not allowed to make the validation in model class, instead use viewModel class. Now I am little confuse on how to put the ***[Required]*** annotations in my viewModel.

**My problem**

This is how the real validation will work
***View***

```
<tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td colspan="2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reg.registerNm, new { @class = "TextBoxAsLabel" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reg.registerNm)
            </td>

        </tr>
```

***ViewModel***

```
public class reg
{  
   [Required]
   public string registerNm {get;set;}
}
```

This will work, but in my **ViewModel**, the structure is different because I need to use data from many table
**My ViewModel**

```
    public class RegisterInfoPA
{    

    public register reg { get; set; }

    public personalInfo pinfo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<maritalInfo> minfo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<eduInfo> edInfo { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<monthlyIncome> monthlyIncomeInfo { get; set; }

    public refundBank refundBK { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<accType> accType { get; set; }  
}
```

so whenever I assign ***[Required]*** annotations here, the validation will not working.
How can I do validation message for my ViewModel, because my viewModel is using

> public register reg { get; set; }

which represent so many fields, which I want, but for validation purpose, I only want one or two certain field to be validated.How can I achieve that?

Thank you .

Comment: Assuming `register` here is one more `class`, why don't you move those 2 fields to separate `class` and inherit them in required classes?

Comment: A view model should not contain properties which are data models. You need to create view models for each of your data models/collections - e.g. `public registerViewModel reg { get; set; }`, `public IEnumerable<maritalInfoViewModel> minfo { get; set; }` etc.

Comment: Please, follow [C# coding standards and naming conventions](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards) if you want other people to easiliy read your code. To be precise, do not use LowerCamelCase for properties.

Comment: It is all about how you'd like to keep your ViewModel. I suggest you can have a property for the registerNm directly in your Viewmodel and have it back to reg when it is sent to db.

Comment: I will try each of your suggestions and will get back soon, and see which one is working for me.

Comment: thank u @GuruprasadRao

Comment: thank u @StephenMuecke

Comment: thank u @YeldarKurmangaliyev I really appreciate the link u gave me

Comment: thank u @ABittersweetLife

Comment: hi guys, none of it works .. :(